# WordPress admin page - how to increase width of side metabox panel

Tags: wordpress

I want to reduce the proportional width of the main editor and increase the width of the metaboxes on the right side. Looks like admin page uses absolute positioning and want to see if there is a reasonable way to achive this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this code in your child theme functions.php and then create a file "admin.css". Just add the styles you wish to override with a higher specificity (you don't want to use !important as it will probably mess up responsiveness).

```
// Update CSS within in Admin
function admin_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style('admin-styles', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/admin.css');
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_style');
```